# VLOOKUP failing to work with dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a field that should populate contact details from a sheet of names, email addresses and whatnot. **`BASE_VesOp`** is the name, grabbed from elsewhere. The contact details are in the dynamic range **`ContactDetails`**, defined as `='Contact details'!$A$2:INDEX('Contact details'!$A$2:$F$201, COUNTA('Contact details'!$A$2:$F$201))`.

I'm using this lookup to get the email address from column 4 of `ContactDetails`, based on the name in `BASE_VesOp`:

```
=VLOOKUP(BASE_VesOp, ContactDetails, 4, FALSE)
```

It keeps giving me a #REF! error, and checking the calc steps gives this:

[image: Lookup error]

I've tried formulating the range differently - column by column, for instance - but keep getting the same error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Why are you creating ContactDetails that way? That formula stops at row 201 so it's not very dynamic. Change ContactDetails to a normal range.

Comment: The reason I'm avoiding that is to avoid having empty spaces in the dropdown - there are unlikely to ever be more than 200 vessel operators, but there are usually far fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFFSET is a clearer way to do your dynamic range. Change Contact Details to:

```
=OFFSET('Contact details'!$A$2$F$2,0,0,COUNTA('Contact details'!$A$2:$F$201))
```

Then, after you have saved this change, in the Name Manager, click on this range definition, it should highlight the intended area on your sheet. This way you can verify it is set correctly.

Comment: It kept popping up an error, but I think that was caused by the typo. I corrected it to `=OFFSET('Contact details'!$A$2:$F$201,0,0,COUNTA('Contact details'!$A$2:$F$201))`, and now it works nicely. Thanks!